# Creating a Basic MVC Project with Unit Tests in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, server-error

I wanted to set up an MVC 2 web application in Visual Studio 2010 using C# as the language. For that, I referred the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410597.aspx and I created the same. When I ran the application by pressing F5, I got an error in my browser. I have attached the error information below.
[image: Server Error]

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: you don't access the page directly in mvc. What is the url when you get this action. What is the actionresult name

Comment: @Tassadaque: http://localhost:12315/Views/Home/Index.aspx is the path it was redirected to and the Action result name is 'index'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC is different from regular ASP.NET. In MVC you are using the http-address to tell your application which method to fire in which class.

In MVC language **methods** are called "*Actions*". And **classes** are called "*Controllers*" (ruffly speaking).
If you want the first view to show, you will have to tell the class "HomeController" to perform its method "Index()". 
You do this by entering the address: "localhost/**Home/Index**"

Please read more here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410269(VS.98).aspx

Comment: When I hit F5, it was redirected to localhost:12315/Views/Home/Index.aspx and the Action result name is 'index'. Then the error was displayed.

Comment: When I started a new MVC 2 project, the test-project didn't add a reference to the main-project. Was this the case for you? Try to start a new project and see if it initializes better. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If your controller is called `MapsController` with an `ViewMaps` action as shown in the tutorial then you should navigate to `/maps/viewmaps` in your browser to execute this action.